# Slow tiles generation for leaflet js

Tags: python, maps, geospatial, leaflet, gdal

I am currently trying to use [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to display images (jpeg or png) instead of maps, I have followed the instructions on [this blog post](http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html) to create the tiles using [gdal2tiles.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) here is the code we used

```
gdal2tile.py -p raster -z 0-5 -w none "SOURCE_PATH.png" "DESTINATION_FOLDER"
```

The command produces the necessary tiles for leaflet, but the problem is that it takes around 2 minutes to create tiles for the attached image (size: 777KB, resolution: 2592x1728) and a disastrous number of tiles of around 1600 file.

I am trying to optimize the time and number of files to generate tiles for leaflet and looking for suggestions, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Like the blog post explains, your image's resolution is too low to zoom further than 3 times. So change that to 0-3 and you'll see things speed up considerably.